# having two versions of (twitter) bootstrap running simultaneously on a web application

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have currently started trying my hand at client side development with bootstrap and angularjs. I've been given a task to make a more or less isolated feature of our website (an angularjs application) and have been working on it but noticed that the bootstrap functions I learned were not working.

Upon inspection I found that our app is using bootstrap 2.3.x and I want to use features of bootstrap 3.0

Because bootstrap has made quite a huge change in its new version, the main web app coders do not want to switch over so that is not an option. (at least not yet).

My question: is there a way I could have my isolated view use bootstrap 3 while the rest of the app uses bootstrap 2? I really don't want to take the time to learn deprecated technology so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I doubt you can do this. If you're using angular, why not use [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) version 0.8

Comment: Which features are you trying to get from bootstrap 3.x? In all honesty it might be easier to re-create them for 2.3.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating an isolated feature on your site, will it be embed in one of the pages or is it a section in its own right? Your app pages can use bootstrap 3.x without it causing problems on other pages if the script links are only in the header of your app pages and not added to other pages in the site. The link will not leak bootstrap 3.x to previous code that does not have these script tags in the header. If that is the case, you can go ahead and use bootstrap 3.x and angular.js and should have no issues.

I would stick your app in a separate folder on the website and design away with the more up-to-date tools.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use some buzzwords here:

- Shadow DOM
- Web Components
- Polymer

> Scoped styling is one of the many features of Shadow DOM. Styles defined inside the shadow tree don’t leak out and page styles don’t bleed in.

https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html

---

### [image]

http://plnkr.co/edit/hypZyjc4yFxIubfOn31N?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.5.2/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="your-component.html">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Bootstrap 3.3.1</h1>
    <your-component></your-component>
  </body>
</html>
```

your-component.html

```
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="your-component">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <template>
        <h1>Bootstrap 2.3.2</h1>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({});
    </script>

</polymer-element>
```

Comment: The preview url does not response the web page as you mentioned. Is any thing changed?

Comment: `https://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer` - *We're sorry, but the polymerosaurus can't find the page you were looking for.* - Something must have changed...

Comment: the result of code at http://plnkr.co/edit/hypZyjc4yFxIubfOn31N?p=preview is not same as you said

Comment: Your question: `Is any thing changed?` - the only thing that could have changes is the `<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">` - I did check and it returns 404... Potentially needs replacing with `https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/polymer/polymer.html` as explained here https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/quick-tour but I'm on corporate network, many websites are blocked.