# use two versions of bootstrap on same project asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have an old asp.net project with bootstrap 2 and i want to upgrade its master page to 3, which only has nabvar.
I want to keep bootstrap 2 in view partials. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: probably impossible...

Comment: Could be a mess Marco.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [having two versions of (twitter) bootstrap running simultaneously on a web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974942/having-two-versions-of-twitter-bootstrap-running-simultaneously-on-a-web-appli)